# Wrapping long text in notification on API level 7

Tags: android, notifications, android-2.1-eclair

In my app I have a service that performs network-related activities and displays notifications if errors occur.  The error text may be reasonably long - to provide enough details.  In newer versions of API I can use `BigTextStyle` to display a long text, however per client's requirements the app must work on API 7 and up (Android 2.1 and above). I got everything else working on API 7, so this is the last thing remaining.

So the question is: how can I display a long message text in the notification on API 7?